# A convex function on a convex set will have a maximum on the boundary

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I am trying to generalise the following proof in n real dimemtions:

Given a convex function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and a convex set $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, we will assume that the function has a locally maximum value over $X$ at $\vec{z}$ for some point in the interior of $X$. This means $\exists \varepsilon>0$, such that $\forall \vec{x}\in B_X(\vec{z}, \varepsilon),\ f(\vec{z})\ge f(\vec{x})$. Where $B_X(\vec{z}, \varepsilon)$  is a ball in $X$ of radius $\varepsilon$ centred around $\vec{z}.$\ \ Now take any two points, which are not $\vec{z}$, in this ball, and call them $\vec{x_1},\ \vec{x_2}$. We know that $f(\vec{z})\ge \max\{f(\vec{x_1}),f(\vec{x_2})\}$, WOLG we pick $f(\vec{x_1})$ to be the larger. This implies $f(\vec{z})\ge (1-t)f(\vec{x_1})+tf(\vec{x_1})\ge(1-t)f(\vec{x_1})+tf(\vec{x_2})$, for $t\in[0,1]$.

However we cannot use this to disporve that $f$ is convex as $\vec{z}$ is not on the segment of $\vec{x_1}, \vec{x_2}$. Is there a way to use my argument with some modification of careful choosing of $\vec{x_1}, \vec{x_2}$, or is it better to prove this using calculus and show that a the function will continue to increase from a minimum point in the convex set?

Comment: There is no reason a convex function can't have a local maximum in the interior of its domain. Take, for example, $f:[0,3] \to \mathbb{R} \, ; \, t \mapsto \begin{cases} 1-t, & 0 \leqslant t \leqslant 1 \\ 0, & 1 \leqslant t \leqslant 2 \\ t-2, & 2 \leqslant t \leqslant 3 \end{cases}$.

It is convex and has a local maximum at the interior point $x = \frac{3}{2}$ of its domain. Now, of course this $f$ will have a maximum on the boundary of its domain, but what I'm getting at is "local maximum at interior point" does not imply "function not convex"

Comment: So in that case I would be better off starting from a minimum point and show that a convex function will have a derivative greater than zero so the value of the function must increase at points past the minimum?